# Two phonegap webviews on one activity

Tags: android, webview, cordova

Is it possible to place two independent webviews to my activity and start different html applications in these two webviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly the answer you're looking for, but is related and may be helpful.

The capability to add PhoneGap to your own WebView is a new feature planned for the next PhoneGap (1.5) release. See this thread:  [PhoneGap Google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/phonegap/simon%24201.5%2420WebView/phonegap/ZGyofW98xkk/_aQ1miL17zsJ)

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking along the lines of two iframes?

```
<iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp